# Keep form parameters in url?

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a jsp page that gets input from the user in a series of forms. First I ask for the user's height, then their weight. I'd like to ask for each on a separate "page". But really I'm just submitting the same jsp file again, only using the values in the url to figure out which form contents I should be showing:

```
String height = request.getParameter("height");
String weight = request.getParameter("weight");
<form>
<%
if (height != null) {
    %>
    Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" />
    <%
} else {
    %>
    Height: <input type="text" name="height" />
    <%
}
%>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So the first run would ask for their height, the second would ask for their weight (if it sees the "height" param is already present in the url). Is that possible? It seems like I lose the params as I progress through each step,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a hidden input field with the height stored in it so you don't lose the height value when asking for weight in the second step:

```
<input type="text" name="weight" />
<input type="hidden" name="height" value="<%= height %>" />
```